# What could be a compelling reason for an incestuous race to diversify into clans?

Tags: magic, fantasy-races, worldbuilding-process

I'm writing a litRPG novel and have created an incestuous race called Purus (a temporary name). Purus are a long-lived race that can live for up to 1000 years. They possess unique magical powers, although I'm still deciding what those are exactly. To maintain their magical abilities and genetic purity, Purus must reproduce with their biological relatives, up to first, second, and third degrees of kinship. However, this makes it impossible for them to diversify, which is something I like in fictional races such as half-elves or dark elves. I'm looking for a better reason why the Purus would diversify into sub-species.

One idea I had was that the Purus' creator god sent revelations to their sages, instructing them to divide the race into clans. Each clan would receive a different set of blessings, mutations, and powers, leading to unique biological and magical traits. Over time, these traits would become more distinct and diverse, making inter-clan marriage taboo due to the risk of disabled offspring. The clans would have different marriage practices, such as monogamy, polygyny, and polyandry.

However, I'm not fully satisfied with this reasoning I come up with. I would appreciate any suggestions for a better explanation for why the Purus would diversify into clans.

Comment: I think you have the premise backwards - isolated pockets of genetics that reproduce within themselves but not outside results in populations that are homogeneous within the small group, but heterogenous across the entire population. Darwin's finches, for example, are a group of diverse birds that all descended from a common ancestor but eventually diverged into different species due to physical isolation on different islands. If this species is naturally incestuous, the different family units will naturally diverge genetically, just like isolated populations on islands.

Comment: I need to agree completely with @NuclearHoagie. As described, your race can't avoid becoming clan-based (family-based) and diversified into sub-species. In fact, the incestuous nature would accelerate the process. True racial homogeneity occurs when genetics are well-spread-out so that genetic "quirks" (think hair color, skin color, eye color, attached ears/non-attached, eye shape, etc.) are weeded out as diversions from a desirable norm. Incestuous lineages would embrace such differences as distinctive of their clan and families. You've already answered your own question.

Comment: When small groups of people live slightly apart from each other, they start to develop small variations in language and even how they look. In the 60's when I was in a small village in Germany, the village a mile away had slight differences in the language. In other places, the people in the next valley looked slightly different. Tony Hillerman mentions visual differences in people from different Navajo groups. It can be surprising how quickly a small group intermarrying can acquire a distinct physical characteristic that other members can identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic reason why a group of intelligent beings develops an internal structure is that it grows too large for all the members to know each other.

Consequently, while in a band everyone can know everyone else well enough to see who's contributing and who's slacking, a tribe is large enough that some kind of structure is needed to keep internal track of things.

Let us suppose that as your race multiplies, they find it too hard to keep track of who is related to whom.  They break into endogamous clans where the clan mothers can keep track of them.

If you do not want them to keep on splitting up after the original clan formation, inventing writing or other forms of keeping track can make it feasible for even large clans to manage.

Answer (score 1):

**Good, Ol'Fashioned Disease**

Now, you didn't say your beings weren't immune to disease, so I'm going to presume they are. What better way to force a society to form small, isolated groups with only limited interaction than some dangerous and deadly disease?

Especially if the disease manifests differently between groups - e.g. one group primarily experiences vomitting and then death, but another goes ghastly white, then dies etc.

This would give you the time and space to have a degree of diversification and the limited contact means that each group will develop unique attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to entangle procreation with the clan system at all?

The clan system can be culture/traditions based and have nothing to do with blood-lines at all.

Especially if, for your race, the act of pro-creating, aka SEX, is not particularly pleasant/enjoyable.
It is a necessary evil to produce children. It is done as needed with a closely related partner as dictated by the need to maintain the blood-line.
Afterwards both partners go their separate ways and back to their own clan and the one that had the child raises it in the culture of their own clan.

You could even make this race hermaphroditic and have both sex-partners produce a child at the same time. One for each of the parents clans.